# can not access usercontrol properties inside main page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control

```
public partial class ConLib_Custom_ClickAndCollect : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string Address
    {
        get
        {
            if (ccTextBox.Text != String.Empty)
                return ccTextBox.Text.ToString();
            else
                return "United Kingdom";
        }
    }

    private Address _clickCollectAddress;
    public Address ClickCollectAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return _clickCollectAddress;
        }
        set
        {
            _clickCollectAddress = value;
        }
    }
}
```

and when i try to use this control in another .ascx page like this.

```
<uc:ClickAndCollect ID="ClickAndCollectPanel" runat="server" Visible="false"
    EnableViewState="true" />
```

and in code behind i can see only Address Property and not ClickCollectAddress property.

```
ClickAndCollectPanel.Address // and can not see this ClickAndCollectPanel.ClickCollectAddress
```

i dont know what is the issue.

please help. thanks

Comment: are you able to build the solution?

Comment: yes...i think i have found the glitch... Address is a separate class and there was one property already declared with Address. so i renamed it to Location ...and it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of conflict. You have a `type` and a `property` both named `Addres` in same class. Rename one of them, then it should be resolved.